# W3 Total Cache - Allow Editors to purge single page cache and all caches

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I would need the Editor role to have access to purge the single page cache and also to flush all the caches for W3 Total Cache.

I tried the solution proposed by @janh in the question below:
[W3 Total Cache - Allow Editors To Purge Single Post From Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663098/w3-total-cache-allow-editors-to-purge-single-post-from-cache/41040134#41040134). But it doesn't work. I guess something has change since then...

Enabling the manage_options capability for Editor role works, but it also gives access to other plugins options, which is not an option for me.

Could anyone provide an updated solution?

Thank a lot.